# Download file using wget changing text encoding

Tags: character-encoding, wget

The webpage I want do get has windows-1251 charset encoding. 
Is there a way to not just simply download this page, but automatically.. um.. convert the text inside to a uft-8?

I have tried to add additional parameters to wget like

```
--header='Accept-Charset: utf-8'
```

but no luck.

Comment: Can you give an example page?

Comment: sure, http://www.popmech.ru/article/12858-kosmicheskiy-grom/

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 ./index.html > ./utf.html
```

to convert the encoding. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_a_text_file%27s_encoding

Comment: possible solution.. but is there a way to solve it with wget only?

Comment: Maybe not directly, but how about `wget -O ./tmp.htm http://www.popmech.ru/article/12858-kosmicheskiy-grom/ && iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 ./tmp.htm > ./output.htm`

Comment: yeah, that works (only it should be -f=windows-1251), but the trouble with that method is that we should know the charset before running this command.